# How to invoke prepare method of Preparable Interface after my own custom interceptor

Tags: struts2

I have created my own Interceptor, `MyInterceptor`, as follows:

```
public class MyInterceptor extends MethodFilterInterceptor
{
String inv=null;    
@Override
    protected String doIntercept(ActionInvocation invocation)
    {
        System.out.println("MyInterceptor fired");
        try
        {
            inv=invocation.invoke();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return inv;      
    }
}
```

My action class is this:

```
public class MyStruts2Class extends ActionSupport implements Preparable
{
    @Override
    public void prepare()
    {
        System.out.println("HI Prepare");
    }
    public String execute()
    {
        System.out.println("Hi Execute");       
        return "success";
    }
}
```

... and my `struts.xml` is this:

```
<struts>
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">
<interceptors>
<interceptor name="myIntercept" class="org.sagar.intercetors.MyInterceptor"/> </interceptors>
<action name="defaultStrutsAction" class="org.sagar.struts.MyStruts2Class" method="execute">
<interceptor-ref name="myIntercept"/> <result name="success">success.jsp</result>
</action>
</struts>
```

My problem is when I fire my `defaultStrutsAction` class, `MyInterceptor` runs fine but the `prepare` method in the Action class is not invoked which it should, as I have implemented the `Preparable` interface.

If I omit this line:

```
<interceptor-ref name="myIntercept"/>
```

... in `struts.xml`, the `prepare` method in the Action class runs fine.

I am new in `Struts2`, but can't figure out what is wrong here.

Comment: You have only configured your interceptor to run for that action, not the default (or any other) stack. You need to configure all interceptors that you want to run, in the order you want them to run in. http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/interceptors.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the prepare interceptor to the interceptor stack for the prepare method to get called in the action. You can do this in a few ways, one is to define the action itself to have the prepare interceptor. Like so. The order matters.

```
<struts>
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">
<interceptors>
<interceptor name="myIntercept" class="org.sagar.intercetors.MyInterceptor"/>               </interceptors>
<action name="defaultStrutsAction" class="org.sagar.struts.MyStruts2Class" method="execute">
<interceptor-ref name="myIntercept"/> 
<interceptor-ref name="prepare"/>  
<result name="success">success.jsp</result>
</action>
</struts>
```

You can also define the interceptor stack in the interceptors tag and use the default-interceptor-ref tag

```
<struts>
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">
<interceptors>
<interceptor name="myIntercept" class="org.sagar.intercetors.MyInterceptor"/>              
    <interceptor-stack name="myStack">
       <interceptor-ref name="myIntercept"/>
       <interceptor-ref name="prepare"/>
    </interceptor-stack>    
</interceptors>
<default-interceptor-ref name="myStack"/>
<action name="defaultStrutsAction" class="org.sagar.struts.MyStruts2Class" method="execute">
<result name="success">success.jsp</result>
</action>
</struts>
```

And finally, what I think your interceptor stack should look like,

```
<struts>
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">
<interceptors>
<interceptor name="myIntercept" class="org.sagar.intercetors.MyInterceptor"/>              
    <interceptor-stack name="myStack">
       <interceptor-ref name="myIntercept"/>
       <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
    </interceptor-stack>    
</interceptors>
<default-interceptor-ref name="myStack"/>
<action name="defaultStrutsAction" class="org.sagar.struts.MyStruts2Class" method="execute">
<result name="success">success.jsp</result>
</action>
</struts>
```

In this example, I ref defaultStack instead of just prepare, because defaultStack already has prepare defined along with other common interceptors that you may want to use. 
in your example when you omit this line

```
 <interceptor-ref name="myIntercept"/>
```

the prepare interceptor gets called because it is in the defaultStack already defined by struts2.

Take a look at the stacks defined in link provided by Steven Benitez. 
Under default configuration.

http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/interceptors.html

Hope that helps.

here is an example of my reply to your comment.

```
<struts>
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">
<interceptors>
<interceptor name="myIntercept" class="org.sagar.intercetors.MyInterceptor"/>               </interceptors>
<action name="defaultStrutsAction" class="org.sagar.struts.MyStruts2Class" method="execute">
<interceptor-ref name="myIntercept"/> 
<interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>  
<result name="success">success.jsp</result>
</action>
</struts>
```

Comment: Thanx Sumit for your answer.So,upto till now,my understanding is if any single interceptor or interceptor stack is explicitly attached with an action in struts.xml then only that interceptor or interceptor stack will be applied for that action and not the defaultStack otherwise the default stack will be applied for that action....right?? As because if this wouldn't like that, **prepare** method would have also been called simultaneously along with my custom interceptor,**myIntercept**.

Comment: When you specify an interceptor explicitly, only the interceptors defined explicitly get called, regardless of what you have for a default stack. You can still add the default stack explicitly, I added an example to the answer. Hope that helps... dont forget to mark the correct answer if it was useful.

Comment: Thnx Sumit for the explanation.I found your answer quite usefull and now I am in a comfortable position...:)